# Video play() doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, video, safari

On my site arielledubois.com, I cannot get my homepage video to play in Safari only. Here is the JS code that I have set in place:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     document.getElementById("bgvid").play();
 }, 3900);
```

I've read that Apple blocks autoplay so you have to click to activate the video; but does anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better use **'canplaythrough'** event.

```
var video = document.getElementById("bgvid");
video.oncanplaythrough = function() {
    video.play();
};
video.src = "your_video_sourse";
```